# Sending update request in Rails 5 edit form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an issue with an edit form on my page to update and save attributes using AJAX in Ruby on Rails 5. The goal is to render the edit form in the same page and then after editing the information submit the form and have the info show back up. Getting the edit form to show up on the page works perfectly fine but after that it just does nothing.

I have a feeling it has something to with where the form is sending to but I can't seem to figure it out. I have searched all over and it seems there are lots of answers out there for rails 3/4 but the request is different for rails 5. From all the examples I can find, my code looks correct, but clearly I'm missing something. I'm still a beginner rails developer but from my understanding the edit form should send an update request to the controller but it doesn't seem to do so. Any help is appreciated. Code below.

**Controller**

```
      def create
        @properties = Property.new(property_params)
        if @properties.save
          flash[:success] = "Property created successfully!"
          redirect_to properties_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def edit
        @properties = Property.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { @properties.save }
          format.js
        end
      end

      def update
        @properties = Property.find(params[:id])
        @property.update_attributes(property_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to property_path }
          format.js
        end
      end
```

**View**

```
    <%= link_to fa_icon("edit", text: "Edit Property"), 
        edit_property_path(@properties), remote: true, class: "btn btn-
        primary btn-large btn-ouline" %>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
    $('div#show-edit').replaceWith('<%= j render("edit_prop_form") %>');
```

**update.js.erb**

```
    $('#edit_property_<%= @properties.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render("properties_display") %>');
```

**_edit_prop_form.html.erb partial**

```
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@properties, layout: :horizontal, control_col: "col-sm-4", remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>


      <%= f.text_field :company, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :address1, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :address2, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :city,     class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :state,    class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :zipcode,  class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.form_group do %>
        <%= f.submit "Edit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

**HTML that edit form renders**

```
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="edit_property_99"
    action="/properties/99" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true"
    method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input
    type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
```

**TL;DR** Edit form renders on page from initial edit button but "Edit" button on the form does not update and save edited info and display original div.

Comment: In the update method, what is @property?

Comment: Well it should be the instance of the property that is being called. But your question makes me think it should be '@properties' instead...

Comment: ....annddd that was the issue the entire time. Pays off to have a second set of eyes and take a step back I guess. Thank you for pointing that out! +1 for you my friend.

Comment: Its always good to keep chrome dev tools open when you work with ajax. have a look here on some tips https://www.jackkinsella.ie/articles/debugging-rails-with-chrome-devtools

Comment: Very cool @sameera207, thanks for the info! If you have any other good resources I'd love to check them out. Feel free to message me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mr12086 pointed out, in my update method `@property` should have been `@properties`. After making the change all worked as expected.